# How to compare the strings using < (Greater than symbol)

Tags: sed, awk

**Below is my input file:**

```
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:16:46.523.177, 2 PS Sensor Value = -5.501000 , Min = -5.583000 , Max = -5.319000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:16:46.523.210, 3 PS Sensor Value = 15.996000 , Min = 15.814000 , Max = 16.078000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:16:46.523.231, 4 PS Sensor Value = -16.505000 , Min = -16.587000 , Max = -16.323000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:16:46.523.263, 5 PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:16:46.523.302, 6 PS Sensor Value = 4.002000 , Min = 3.820000 , Max = 4.084000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:17:46.481.557, 1 PS Sensor Value = 6.199000 , Min = 6.017000 , Max = 6.281000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:17:46.518.691, 2 PS Sensor Value = -5.503000 , Min = -5.585000 , Max = -5.321000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:17:46.523.156, 3 PS Sensor Value = 15.996000 , Min = 15.814000 , Max = 16.078000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:17:46.523.195, 4 PS Sensor Value = -16.505000 , Min = -16.587000 , Max = -16.323000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:17:46.523.221, 5 PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:17:46.523.240, 6 PS Sensor Value = 4.002000 , Min = 3.820000 , Max = 4.084000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:18:46.480.644, 1 PS Sensor Value = 6.199000 , Min = 6.017000 , Max = 6.281000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:18:46.522.615, 2 PS Sensor Value = -5.501000 , Min = -5.583000 , Max = -5.319000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:18:46.522.729, 3 PS Sensor Value = 15.996000 , Min = 15.814000 , Max = 16.078000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:18:46.522.765, 4 PS Sensor Value = -16.505000 , Min = -16.587000 , Max = -16.323000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:18:46.522.788, 5 PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000
PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:18:46.522.810, 6 PS Sensor Value = 4.002000 , Min = 3.820000 , Max = 4.084000
```

I need to compare the PS Sensor Value, Min and Max value. (Min greater than PS Sensor greater than Max)

I'm expecting the output like below and here I should have only the normal lines.

**What is normal lines? :** 
If Min value greater than PS Sensor value && PS Sensor value  is greater than Max value then the line is normal lines and that should removed.

**Expected Output:** 
                                                                                                                                  PA43410-2  PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000
PA43410-2 PS Sensor Value = 6.199000 , Min = 6.017000 , Max = 6.281000

Eg:

```
   If   Min < PS sensor value < Max,    // Don’t care the normal  lines.
         Throw this line away.
   Else  
        Pull this line to consolidated new file. //Only focus on abnormal lines.
```

Comment: 1) That's a less than symbol. 2) What have you tried? Are you committed to particular technologies? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Why do you need `sed`? And why do you need the `<` symbol?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `awk`. Since `awk` splits its input into fields on whitespace (by default), the PS sensor value will be field 7 (`$7`), the min will be `$11` and the max will be `$15`.  You can, therefore, do:

```
awk  '$7>$11 && $7<$15' file > new.file
```

The default action when an expression evaluates to true in `awk` is to print the current line. Therefore, the command above will print all lines whose 7th field is between the `min` and `max` values.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. IPA43410-2  PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000
PA43410-2 PS Sensor Value = 6.199000 , Min = 6.017000 , Max = 6.281000
PA43410-2 PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000
PA43410-2 PS Sensor Value = 6.199000 , Min = 6.017000 , Max = 6.281000
PA43410-2 PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000

Comment: @AlbertLévay I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. Do you mean that the min and max values should be taken from the values given on each line? If so, you need to _tell us_. Please edit your question and clarify. Anyway, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm expecting the output like below and here I should have only the normal lines. What is normal lines? : If Min value greater than PS Sensor value && PS Sensor value  is greater than Max value then the line is normal lines and that should removed.                                                                                                                                        PA43410-2  PS Sensor Value = 6.509000 , Min = 6.327000 , Max = 6.591000
PA43410-2 PS Sensor Value = 6.199000 , Min = 6.017000 , Max = 6.281000

Comment: @AlbertLévay yes, and the min/max should be taken from each line, right? Your question didn't make that clear, I thought you wanted to set the min/max manually. Did you try the updated answer?

Comment: Hey Terdon. Yes I tried the updated one. this is what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlbertLévay glad to hear it. I edited to only give the answer you needed. If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Yes I will do that but before I have one more question. How to remove the string after a comma from my first awk spilts?                           PA43410-2,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,19:16:46.523.177,                         I want the output like below:                                                                                PA43410-2 PS Sensor Value = -15.501000 , Min = -5.583000 , Max = -5.319000

Comment: @AlbertLévay that's a whole different question but, briefly, you could do `awk  '{if($7>$11 && $7<$15){sub(/,.*/,"",$1);print}}' file`.

Comment: Hey Terdon, I have one more file. PA43171-7,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,12:01:16.086.660, Valid Sensor Reading,Date = 08-19-2014  ,  Time = 12:01:16 Voltage Sensor=11 ,  V$
$=11 , Voltage Sensor Value=9.927417 , Min=9.450000 , Max=11.550000 same like above output I'm expecting. The problem is here I cannot use awk to split. Here Min Value < Voltage Sensor < Max Value. How can I approach this? Thanks

Comment: @AlbertLévay please ask a new question

Comment: Hey Terdon. In the same problem if the Min and Max values are placed in different order for every alternative lines. Eg: Min = -5.583000 , Max = -5.319000   - --- 1st Line. Max = -5.319000  Min = -5.583000 ---- 2nd Line. Min = -5.583000 , Max = -5.319000 --- 3rd Line. If this is the case how do we approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlbertLévay please take the [tour] to understand how the site works. This answer seems to have solved your original question, so please [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left, and post a new question for any follow up issues.