# How to compare (using greater than and less than symbols) strings using awk

Tags: awk

This is my input file:

```
PA43171-7,1,3,/vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp,48,12:01:16.086‌​.660, Valid Sensor Reading,Date = 08-19-2014 , Time = 12:01:16 Voltage Sensor=11 , V$ $=11 , Voltage Sensor Value=9.927417 , Min=9.450000 , Max=11.550000
```

I need to compare the Voltage Sensor Value, Min and Max value. (Min greater than Voltage Sensor Value greater than Max)

I'm expecting the below output from my input file:

```
PA43171-7 Date = 08-19-2014 , Time = 12:01:16 Voltage Sensor Value=9.927417 , Min=9.450000 , Max=11.550000
```

Comment: Yes but this is little tricky. The problem is here I cannot use awk to split because I have lot of whitespaces.  How can I approach this? Thanks

Comment: If you can't use awk, why are you using awk?

Comment: I reply, but fail to see what you compare to what ...

Comment: What makes you think you can't use awk? Just count the fields and use the right number.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 awk -F, '{ printf "%s %s, %s %s %s µs\n",$1,$8,substr($9,1,15),$11,$12,$13 ;}' file
```

I get position of field using

```
 awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%2d: %s\n",i,$i;}' a
 1: PA43171-7
 2: 1
 3: 3
 4: /vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp
 5: 48
 6: 12:01:16.086‌​.660
 7:  Valid Sensor Reading
 8: Date = 08-19-2014
 9:  Time = 12:01:16 Voltage Sensor=11
10:  V$ $=11
11:  Voltage Sensor Value=9.927417
12:  Min=9.450000
13:  Max=11.550000
```

Edit: (I see problem with dupplicate, here no white arround `=` )

## 1- get field index

(for first line only, I supposed all lines look alike)

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[,=]" } NR == 1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%2d: %s\n",i,$i;}' a
 1: PA43171-7
 2: 1
 3: 3
 4: /vobs/atlas-idc/src/utils/logger/IDCLogger/IDC.cpp
 5: 48
 6: 12:01:16.086‌​.660
 7:  Valid Sensor Reading
 8: Date
 9:  08-19-2014
10:  Time
11:  12:01:16 Voltage Sensor
12: 11
13:  V$ $
14: 11
15:  Voltage Sensor Value
16: 9.927417
17:  Min
18: 9.450000
19:  Max
20: 11.550000
```

## 2- actual test (according to [How to compare the strings using < (Greater than symbol)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273333/how-to-compare-the-strings-using-greater-than-symbol) for the record)

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[,=]" }
    $16 < $18 { print "too low:%s\n",$0 }
    $16 > $20 { print "too high:%s\n",$0 } ' a
```

Comment: Hey Archemar, Thanks for your reply. However I have plenty of lines in my input file. If that is the case this won't work. I'm a right?

Comment: 1) I edit to parse first line only, 2) in part 2, adjust actual value for $16, $18 and all. this should work regardless number of line, however if line format change within file, this won't work.

Comment: Hey Archemar thanks for the help. I would like to add few things. One of my output file has the data like below.  (First line last Max 1st Min 2nd on the next line Min 1st and Max 2nd and then the last line again Max 1st and Min 2nd and it is going like this) how do we approach this? PA43171-7 Voltage Sensor Value=15.925745 , Min=15.100000 , Max=17.100000
PA43171-7 Voltage Sensor value=-16.480005 , Max=-15.900000 , Min =-17.900000
PA43171-7 Voltage Sensor Value=-16.480005 , Min=-17.900000 , Max=-15.900000